# LSTM and labels

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tflearn

Lets start off with "I know ML cannot predict stock markets better than monkeys." 
But I just want to go through with it.

My question is a theretical one. 
Say I have date, open, high, low, close as columns. So I guess I have 4 features, open, high, low, close.

'my_close' is going to be my label(answer) and I will use the 'close' 7 days from current row. Basically i shift the 'close' column up 7 rows and make it a new column called 'my_close'.

LSTMs work on sequences. So say the sequence I set is 20 days. 
hence my shape will be (1000days of data, 20 day as a sequence, 3 features).

The problem that is bothering me is should these 20 days or rows of data, have the exact same label? or can they have individual labels ? 
Or have i misunderstood the whole theory?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, You want to predict the current day's stock price using previous 7 days stock values. The way your building your inputs and outputs require some modification before feeding into the model.

Your making mistake in understanding timesteps(in your sequences).
Timesteps(sequences) in layman terms is the total number of inputs we will consider while predicting the output. In your case, it will be 7(not 20) as we will be using previous 7 days data to predict the current day's output.

Your Input should be previous 7 days of info

[F11,F12,F13],[F21,F22,F23],........,[F71,F72,F73]

Fij in this, F represents the feature, i represents timestep and j represents feature number.

and the output will be the stock price of the 8th day.
Here your model will analyze previous 7 days inputs and predict the output.
So to answer your question You will have a common label for previous 7 days input.

I strongly recommend you to study a bit more on LSTM's.

Comment: Hi! can I ask you another question. 

I see some people use a window (or seq len, or time sequence) of just 1, quite defeats the purpose of LSTMs right? Altough I have to say, it seems a window of 1 gives the best results?

If you have a look at this link. No need to read in detail, you can roughly see what she is doing. It plots a great graph but it screws my head in when you use only a 1 sequence len. 
http://www.python36.com/predict-cryptocurrency-price-using-lstm/ 

any ideas?

Comment: Yes, your right.! Even though her result seems to be very good in reality it isn't. Please read the 2nd-second comment by  William Brown in that link.

Comment: Multi step prediction in lstm. I have seen some code on this but they take in only one feature. For multi feature, multi step is not possible or absolutely not accurate right? In the context of stock price prediction, lets say i have 7 other features, lets say, open, high, low, ma, momentum, rsi and cci. I predict the next 1 step close price. But i cannot get step 2 and 3 because i do not have the next high low and open. Whcih then is not possible to get the next rsi, cci, momentum to pass into the model.predict(). So there is no way to make this work correct?